# Need to POST xml string to 3rd party api, using gravity forms

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, post, curl

I need have a gform submission POST to third party api as xmldata.

Url that data needs to POST to:

https://www.3rdparty.com/api/lead/insertRecord?apiauthkey=yourapikey&secretkey=yoursecretkey&xmlData=yourxmldata

XML Format Needed:

```
<crcloud>
  <lead>
    <type>Client</type>
    <firstname>Scott</firstname>
    <lastname>James</lastname>
    <client_assigned_to>Bill Smith</client_assigned_to>
  </lead>
</crcloud>
```

I have a curl function written but I am receiving a parsing error when posting. I have validated the xml and it is correct. I can also paste the xml data that prints out directly behind my url and get the result I want.

```
<?php

add_action("gform_after_submission", "set_post_content", 10, 2);
function set_post_content($entry, $form){

function post_to_url($url, $post) {
$fields = '';
foreach($post as $key => $value) {
$fields .= $key . '=' . $value . '&';
}
rtrim($fields, '&');

$url = 'https://www.3rdparty.com/api/lead/insertRecord?apiauthkey=yourapikey&secretkey=yoursecretkey&xmlData=yourxmldata';

$post = curl_init();

curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_POST, count($data));
curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

$result = curl_exec($post);
echo $post; //Resource id #*** currently
echo $result; //False 4404 XML parsing error currently
curl_close($post);
}

if($form["id"] == 2){//sign up now

$data = array(
"type" =>     $entry["31"],      
"firstname" =>     $entry["3"], 
"lastname" =>     $entry["4"], 
"client_assigned_to" =>     $entry["34"]);       

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<crcloud/>');
$lead = $xml->addchild('lead');
$data = array_flip($data);
array_walk_recursive($data, array ($xml, 'addChild'));

print $xml->asXML();

post_to_url($url, $xml);

}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this curl header as well to let the server know that you are sending them xml

```
curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, 
    array('Content-Type: application/xml')
);
```

In any case if you are not sending the XML data(in your example I didn't see you to post xml). Here it is:

```
$post_data = "<crcloud>
  <lead>
    <type>$client</type>
    <firstname>$user</firstname>
    <lastname>$name</lastname>
    <client_assigned_to>$assigned</client_assigned_to>
  </lead>
</crcloud>";

curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
```

Comment: still errors out, Is there a way to verify what exactly is being sent to ensure that the format is correct?

Comment: Yes, you can use verbose option to check what are being transferred. `curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);`

Comment: Also check my updated answer. It shows how you need to send xml data. Just make the xml using your post parameters.

Comment: I am still working on this, the payload its sending is 373 characters but I still unable to view the actual payload to see if its trying to send the xml or not, I believe I am getting closer through. In regards to the the xml I am converting it to xml with the following:$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<crcloud/>');
$lead = $xml->addchild('lead');
$data = array_flip($data);
array_walk_recursive($data, array ($xml, 'addChild'));
and then trying to post that with : post_to_url($url, $xml);